# fetch list of sublayouts used by item in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.1

I'm using `Sitecore 7.1` with `MVC`.

I need to get the item ID of the sublayout or rendering used for a particular Sitecore items. 
Is there a way i fetch list of sublayouts/rendering used by an item in sitecore using .net.
Could some post the necessary code for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The traditional way to get an array of renderings prior to Sitecore MVC is:

`Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false)`

I believe this will return a list of renderings in both a WebForms and MVC context.

Specific to MVC, you can also get a list of renderings by using the current `RenderingContext` or `PageContext` via:

`RenderingContext.Current.PageContext.PageDefinition.Renderings`

or

`PageContext.Current.PageDefinition.Renderings`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).RenderingID);
```

Also see [Using the DataSource Field with Sitecore Sublayouts](http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts/).

Comment: this code can only get me the the sublayout of current Item or in other words, in the current "this" context. what if I want a particular item ?